# In View(CakePHP), the proper way to get current controller?

Tags: cakephp-2.0

In View, I can get action by using

```
$this->action
```

But, I cannot get controller name by

```
$this->controller
```

What is the proper way to get current controller in View?

Comment: If you need this to build links to actions in *current* controller, remember that you can just *omit* the `'controller'` key in the routing array.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Use `$this->params['controller']` to get the current controller.

You can do a `debug($this->params)` to see other available variables.

Comment: `$this->params['controller']` returns: `something_foo`. This means you are using the `somethingFooController`

Answer (score 12):

You can get controller like this:

```
echo "<pre>controller:".$this->request->params['controller']."</pre>";
```

Although `$this->params` is shorter, `$this->request->params` is more autocomplete friendly.  You can check the autocomplete options from this question: [PHPStorm autocomplete for CakePHP custom helpers in view files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16905153/phpstorm-autocomplete-for-cakephp-custom-helpers-in-view-files)

Other data about request can be taken like this:

```
echo "<pre>action:".$this->request->params['action']."</pre>";

echo "<pre>request:"; print_r( $this->request ); echo "</pre>";

echo "<details><summary>this:</summary><pre>"; 
      print_r( $this ); echo "</pre></details>";
```

Edit:
As of CakePHP 3 `$this->params` shortcut is removed. So you should user `$this->request->params['controller']` for CakePHP 3.
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-0-migration-guide.html#id2
Also note that first character of controller is uppercase. It was lowercase in Cakephp 2.

Comment: Instead of echo "<pre>#code_here#</pre>"; you might want to use "debug()"

Answer (score 10):

`$this->name` also give you controller's name.
Their difference with `$this->params['controller']` is it's first letter capitalized

```
debug($this->name);
debug($this->params['controller']);
```

Results in:

```
 \app\Controller\AppController.php (line 176)

'Users'

\app\Controller\AppController.php (line 177)

'users'
```

Answer (score 6):

I am using cakephp 3.2

```
$this->params['controller'] - It is not working, showing error message as bellow..
```

> "Missing Helper"

**Following code is working properly in cakephp 3.2**

```
$this->request->params['controller'] - Working
```

Answer (score 4):

To get the current controller, Try this :`$this->params['controller']`

To get the current action, Try this :`$this->params['action']`.

Answer (score 3):

For cakephp 3.6 and later:

Although above solutions will work but it gives deprecated warning and will not work in cakephp 4.
So It is better to use the following code to get the controller name. It will work in view page and controllers as well.

```
$this->request->getParam('controller')
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the current,

- controller: `$this->params['controller']`
- action: `$this->params['action']`
- arguments:`$this->params['pass']`

Answer (score 0):

All the other solutions are to get the controller name... I need the controller itself, so I did the following function in an AdminHelper.php called by `$this->Admin->_getController('MyControllerName')` into the view.ctp file

```
/******************************************************************
 * 
 ******************************************************************/
function _getController( $pControllerName ){
    if ( ! isset($this->controllersArray[$pControllerName]) ){
        $importRes = App::import('Controller', $pControllerName);// The same as require('controllers/users_controller.php');
        $strToEval = "\$controller = new ".$pControllerName."Controller;";
        $evalRes = eval($strToEval);
        if ( $evalRes === false ){
            throw new AppException("Eval returned an error into ".__FILE__." getController()");
        }
        $controller->constructClasses();// If we want the model associations, components, etc to be loaded
        $this->controllersArray[$pControllerName] = $controller;
    }

    $result = $this->controllersArray[$pControllerName];
    return $result;
}
```

**Note:** don't forget to declare it into the controller you'll use for example:

- people/view.ctp -> `$this->Admin->_getController('MyControllerName')`
- PeopleController.ctp -> `var $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Admin');`
- AdminHelper.ctp -> `function _getController(...`

Answer (score 0):

Since: 3.7.7 to get the View's controller name use $this->getName();