# How to know which controller has rendered a layout in cakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Most of the views in the app render a `default` layout. It also has a navigation menu which purpose is to navigate users through the controllers and it looks like this:

```
<li class="dashboard"><?php echo $this->Html->link('dashboard', array('controller'=>'events', 'action'=>'dashboard'))?></li>
<li class="users"><?php echo $this->Html->link('users', array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'index'))?></li>
<li class="dates"><?php echo $this->Html->link('dates', array('controller'=>'dates', 'action'=>'index'))?></li>
<li class="projets"><?php echo $this->Html->link('sager', array('controller'=>'projcets', 'action'=>'index'))?></li>
```

Based on which controller had rendered the layout, I would like to add `active` to `<li class="">` so I could style that particular element differently.

Any help or guidance on how to get to know which controller had rendered the layout is much appreciated.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13034267/in-viewcakephp-the-proper-way-to-get-current-controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$this->request->controller` to get the current controller.

Use `$this-action` to get the current action.

Use `$this->request->method()` to get the current method.